# GAMS : Infeasible solution for solving non-linear problem (NLP)

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, gams-math

I am trying to solve non-linear probrem (NLP) using GMAS. However, I am getting output "Infeasible solution".The material balance equation in chemical engineering, which describe in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0009250922000665).

```
$title a membrane separation model
Sets
     gas   component gas name   / Gas1, Gas2, Gas3, Gas4 /
     m   membrane module      / module1, module2 /;

Parameters

     q(gas) permeance Q
       /    Gas1        89e-4
            Gas2        71.2e-4
            Gas3        4.45e-4
            Gas4        1.78e-4 /
    
     x_init_gas(gas) process feed component
       /    Gas1        0.19
            Gas2        0.01
            Gas3        0.73
            Gas4        0.07 /
    
     membrane_area(m) area settings
       /    module1     222.92
            module2     164.45 /
     
     high_pressure(m) feed side high pressure
       /    module1     3.5
            module2     3.5 /
    
     low_pressure(m) feed side high pressure
       /    module1     0.105
            module2     0.105 / ;


Scalar
     U  fresh feed flow rate    /90         /
     Rg                         /8.3144     /
     temperature                /313        /
     f_mh                       /200        /
     f_cp                       /1          /
     etha_cp                    /0.7        /
     f_cc                       /0.27       /
     f_wk                       /0.1        /
     f_mr                       /90         /
     t_m                        /0.05       /
     f_mt                       /0.05       /
     f_sg                       /35e-9      /
     t_wk                       /300        /
     f_hv                       /43e6       /
     gamma_LB lower bounds for pressure ratio   /0.01/
     gamma_UB upper bounds for pressure ratio   /20/;

Variables
     B(m, gas)
     E(m)
     D(m)
     T(m, gas)
     Tdot(m, gas)
     Tdotdot(m, gas)
     total_annual_cost ;

T.l(m, gas)        =   0.8           ;
Tdot.l(m, gas)     =   0.8           ;
Tdotdot.l(m, gas)  =   0.8           ;
B.l(m, gas)        =   1.5        ;
E.l(m)        =   1        ;
D.l(m)        =   1e-4        ;

T.lo(m, gas)        =   0           ;
Tdot.lo(m, gas)     =   0           ;
Tdotdot.lo(m, gas)  =   0           ;
D.lo(m)             =   min(q('Gas1'), q('Gas2'), q('Gas3'), q('Gas4'))    ;

T.up(m, gas)        =   1-gamma_LB  ;
Tdot.up(m, gas)     =   1-gamma_LB  ;
Tdotdot.up(m, gas)  =   1-gamma_LB  ;
D.up(m)             =   max(q('Gas1'), q('Gas2'), q('Gas3'), q('Gas4'))    ;

Positive Variable
     F_x(m, gas)
     F(m)
     xF(m, gas)
     L_x(m, gas)
     L(m)
     xR(m, gas)
     V_x(m, gas)
     V(m)
     yP(m, gas)
     Lret_x(gas)
     Lret
     xRet(gas)
     Vper_x(gas)
     Vper
     yPer(gas)
     Mix_x(m, gas)
     Mix(m)
     x_Mix(m, gas);
     
F_x.l(m, gas)   =   5   ;
F.l(m)          =   20  ;
xF.l(m, gas)    =   0.25 ;
L_x.l(m, gas)   =   5   ;
L.l(m)          =   20  ;
xR.l(m, gas)    =   0.25 ;
V_x.l(m, gas)   =   2.5   ;
V.l(m)          =   10  ;
yP.l(m, gas)    =   0.25 ;
Lret_x.l(gas)   =   5   ;
Lret.l          =   20  ;
xRet.l(gas)     =   0.25 ;
Vper_x.l(gas)   =   2.5   ;
Vper.l          =   10  ;
yPer.l(gas)     =   0.25 ;
Mix_x.l(m, gas) =   10   ;
Mix.l(m)        =   30   ;
x_Mix.l(m, gas) =   0.25 ;

F_x.lo(m, gas)   =   0   ;
F.lo(m)          =   0   ;
xF.lo(m, gas)    =   0   ;
L_x.lo(m, gas)   =   0   ;
L.lo(m)          =   0   ;
xR.lo(m, gas)    =   0   ;
V_x.lo(m, gas)   =   0   ;
V.lo(m)          =   0   ;
yP.lo(m, gas)    =   0   ;
Lret_x.lo(gas)   =   0   ;
Lret.lo          =   0   ;
xRet.lo(gas)     =   0   ;
Vper_x.lo(gas)   =   0   ;
Vper.lo          =   0   ;
yPer.lo(gas)     =   0   ;
Mix_x.lo(m, gas) =   0   ;
Mix.lo(m)        =   0   ;
x_Mix.lo(m, gas) =   0   ;
   
F_x.up(m, gas)   =   30     ;
F.up(m)          =   30     ;
xF.up(m, gas)    =   1.0    ;
L_x.up(m, gas)   =   30     ;
L.up(m)          =   30     ;
xR.up(m, gas)    =   1.0    ;
V_x.up(m, gas)   =   30     ;
V.up(m)          =   30     ;
yP.up(m, gas)    =   1.0    ;
Lret_x.up(gas)   =   30     ;
Lret.up          =   30     ;
xRet.up(gas)     =   1.0    ;
Vper_x.up(gas)   =   30     ;
Vper.up          =   30     ;
yPer.up(gas)     =   1.0    ;
Mix_x.up(m, gas) =   30     ;
Mix.up(m)        =   40     ;
x_Mix.up(m, gas) =   1.0    ;

Parameter
     u_x(gas)   feed flow rate for component g
     G(m)       parameter G ;
     
        u_x(gas) = U * x_init_gas(gas) ;
      
        G(m) = low_pressure(m) / high_pressure(m) ;


Equations
     cost        define objective function
     const_module_1(m, gas)
     const_module_2(m)
     const_module_3(m)
     const_module_4(m, gas)
     const_module_5(m)
     const_module_6(m, gas)
     const_module_7(m)
     const_module_8(m, gas)
     const_module_9(m, gas)
     const_module_10(m, gas)
     const_module_11(m, gas)
     const_module_12(m, gas)
     const_module_13(m, gas)
     const_module_14(m)
     const_module_15(m)
     const_module_16(m)
     const_module_17(m)
     const_module_18(m)
     const_module_19(m)
     
     tight_constraint_1(m, gas)
     tight_constraint_2(m, gas)
     tight_constraint_3(gas)
     tight_constraint_4(m, gas)
     tight_constraint_5(m, gas)
     tight_constraint_6(m, gas)
     
     const_mixer1_1(gas)
     const_mixer1_2
     const_mixer1_3(gas)
     
     const_mixer2_1(gas)
     const_mixer2_2
     const_mixer2_3(gas)
     
     const_mixer_module_1(m, gas)
     const_mixer_module_2(m)
     const_mixer_module_3(m, gas)
     
     const_mixer_retentate_1(gas)
     const_mixer_retentate_2
     const_mixer_retentate_3(gas)
     
     const_mixer_permeate_1(gas)
     const_mixer_permeate_2
     const_mixer_permeate_3(gas)
     
     const_component_mixer(m)
     const_component_retentate
     const_component_permeate
     
     const_overall_1(gas)
     const_overall_2
     const_overall_3(gas);

cost ..        total_annual_cost  =e=  (f_cc*(1+f_wk)*f_mh*sum(m, membrane_area(m))+f_cp*(Rg*temperature*sum(gas, V_x("module2", gas))*log(high_pressure("module1")/low_pressure("module2")))/etha_cp
                                            +f_mr / t_m * (sum(m, membrane_area(m)))
                                            +f_mt * f_mh*sum(m, membrane_area(m))+f_cp*(Rg*temperature*sum(gas, V_x("module2", gas))*log(high_pressure("module1")/low_pressure("module2")))/etha_cp
                                            +(f_sg*t_wk)/(f_hv*etha_cp)*(Rg*temperature*sum(gas, V_x("module2", gas))*log(high_pressure("module1")/low_pressure("module2")))*24*3600 
                                            +f_sg*t_wk*sum(gas, Vper_x(gas))*yPer("Gas1")/(xRet("Gas1")+1e-3))
                                            /(U*t_wk);

const_module_1(m, gas) ..       B(m, gas) =e= 1 + q(gas) * E(m) ;

const_module_2(m) ..            low_pressure(m)/high_pressure(m) =e= D(m) * E(m) ;

const_module_3(m) ..            D(m) =e= sum(gas, q(gas)*T(m, gas)) ;

const_module_4(m, gas) ..       xR(m, gas) =e= T(m, gas) * B(m, gas) ;

const_module_5(m) ..            sum(gas, Tdotdot(m, gas)) =e= 1 - low_pressure(m)/high_pressure(m) ;

const_module_6(m, gas) ..       Tdot(m, gas) =e= xF(m, gas) - low_pressure(m)/high_pressure(m) * yP(m, gas) ;

const_module_7(m) ..            sum(gas, Tdot(m, gas)) =e= 1 - low_pressure(m)/high_pressure(m) ;

const_module_8(m, gas) ..       2*T(m, gas)**0.3275 =e= Tdot(m, gas)**0.3275 + Tdotdot(m, gas)**0.3275 ;

const_module_9(m, gas) ..       V_x(m, gas) =e= q(gas) * T(m, gas) * high_pressure(m) * membrane_area(m) ;

const_module_10(m, gas) ..      F_x(m, gas) =e= L_x(m, gas) + V_x(m, gas) ;

const_module_11(m, gas) ..      F_x(m, gas) =e= xF(m, gas) * F(m) ;

const_module_12(m, gas) ..      L_x(m, gas) =e= xR(m, gas) * L(m) ;

const_module_13(m, gas) ..      V_x(m, gas) =e= yP(m, gas) * V(m) ;

const_module_14(m) ..           F(m) =e= sum(gas, F_x(m, gas)) ;

const_module_15(m) ..           L(m) =e= sum(gas, L_x(m, gas)) ;

const_module_16(m) ..           V(m) =e= sum(gas, V_x(m, gas)) ;

const_module_17(m) ..           sum(gas, xF(m, gas)) =e= 1 ;

const_module_18(m) ..           sum(gas, xR(m, gas)) =e= 1 ;

const_module_19(m) ..           sum(gas, yP(m, gas)) =e= 1 ;

tight_constraint_1(m, gas) ..   xR(m, gas) =l= xF(m, gas) ;

tight_constraint_2(m, gas) ..   xF(m, gas) =l= yP(m, gas) ;

tight_constraint_3(gas) ..      B("module1", gas) =g= B("module2", gas) ;

tight_constraint_4(m, gas) ..   xF(m, gas) - gamma_UB * yP(m, gas) =l= Tdot(m, gas) ;

tight_constraint_5(m, gas) ..   Tdot(m, gas) =l= xF(m, gas) - gamma_LB * yP(m, gas) ;

tight_constraint_6(m, gas) ..   T(m, gas) =l= (Tdot(m, gas) + Tdotdot(m, gas)) / 2 ;

const_mixer1_1(gas) ..          Mix_x("module1", gas) =e= U*x_init_gas(gas) + V_x("module2", gas) ;

const_mixer1_2 ..               Mix("module1") =e= U + V("module2") ;

const_mixer1_3(gas) ..          Mix("module1")*x_Mix("module1", gas) =e= U*x_init_gas(gas) + V("module2")*yP("module2", gas) ;

const_mixer2_1(gas) ..          Mix_x("module2", gas) =e= V_x("module1", gas) ;

const_mixer2_2 ..               Mix("module2") =e= V("module1") ;

const_mixer2_3(gas) ..          Mix("module2")*x_Mix("module2", gas) =e= V("module1")*yP("module1", gas) ;

const_mixer_module_1(m, gas)..  Mix_x(m, gas) =e= F_x(m, gas) ;

const_mixer_module_2(m) ..      Mix(m) =e= F(m) ;

const_mixer_module_3(m, gas) .. Mix(m)*x_Mix(m, gas) =e= F(m) * xF(m, gas) ;

const_mixer_retentate_1(gas) .. Lret_x(gas) =e= L_x("module2", gas) ;

const_mixer_retentate_2 ..      Lret =e= L("module2") ;

const_mixer_retentate_3(gas) .. Lret * xRet(gas) =e= L("module2") * xR("module2", gas) ;

const_mixer_permeate_1(gas) ..  Vper_x(gas) =e= V_x("module1", gas) ;

const_mixer_permeate_2 ..       Vper =e= V("module1") ;

const_mixer_permeate_3(gas) ..  Vper*yPer(gas) =e= V("module1") * yP("module1", gas) ;

const_component_mixer(m) ..     sum(gas, x_Mix(m, gas)) =e= 1 ;

const_component_retentate ..    sum(gas, xRet(gas)) =e= 1 ;

const_component_permeate ..     sum(gas, yPer(gas)) =e= 1 ;

const_overall_1(gas) ..         U * x_init_gas(gas) =e= Lret_x(gas) + Vper_x(gas) ;
const_overall_2 ..              U =e= Lret + Vper ;
const_overall_3(gas) ..         U * x_init_gas(gas) =e= Lret*xRet(gas) + Vper*yPer(gas) ;

Model transport /all/ ;

Solve transport using nlp minimizing total_annual_cost ;

Display F.m ;
```

Output describes that this problem is infeasible.
I have no idea to solve this error.
Could you please help me solve it? Thank you very much!

Comment: If the paper shows a solution, plug this into the model using `x.fx = ` and see where the infeasibilities are. This is a fairly foolproof approach (of course the paper may have typos).

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance.
Is it possible to insert ```x.Fx=``` to see where the impossible is?

Comment: Yes, fix all variables to their optimal levels (as reported in the paper), run the model and see where the infeasibilities are. If you don't know how to fix variables, check the documentation for the FX variable suffix. Or ask your teacher.

Comment: I checked the documentation and understood that I can fix the value of a variable by writing ```x.fx```.
I appreciate your help !